# Нажать radiobutton независимо от положения окна

Tags: python, autoit

Делаю автоматическую установку приложения PYTHON + AUTOIT.

В окне лиц.соглашения надо нажать радиобаттон "Принимаю лиц.соглашение".

Я смогла это сделать с помощью `autoit.mouse_click`, но, если разрешение экрана будет другим, то работать не будет.

Autoit v3 Win Info

**Window**

```
Title:  Установка Программы 
Class:  TkTopLevel 
Position:   689, 349 Size:  506, 379 
Style:  0x16CA0008 
ExStyle:    0x00000100 
Handle: 0x001214EC
```

**Control**

```
Class:  TkChild 
Instance:   335 
ClassnameNN:    TkChild335 
Name:    Advanced 
(Class):    [CLASS:TkChild; INSTANCE:335] 
ID:  
Text:   
Position:   186, 251 
Size:   304, 21 
ControlClick 
Coords: 10, 13 
Style:  0x56000000 
ExStyle:    0x00000004 
Handle: 0x001A0AF6
```

**Mouse**

```
Position:   888, 639 
Cursor ID:  0 
Color:  0xB9B9B9
```

**StatusBar
ToolsBar**

Comment: Представь что RadioButton это на самом деле не кнопка в окошке, а реально окошко в окошке с картинкой кнопки. В Windows есть функция EnumWindows которая обходит окошки. https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinList.htm , а ещё есть функция EnumChildWindows - которая энумирует компоненты Child, в AutoIT не знаю но вроде вот так реализована - https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_WinAPI_EnumChildWindows.htm  Получаешь реальную позицию X,Y,Width,Height относительно окна, и жмякаешь мышой в окошко с кнопкой.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, с вашей помощью я немного продвинулась. К сожалению, я не могу использовать виндовые функции, т.к. потом мне надо запускать скрипт на linux..
Я взяла autoit.win_get_pos и с помощью этой функции узнала координаты окна, но застопорилась на этапе mouse_click, т.к. не могу понять как правильно высчитать координаты x,y относительно окна..(

Comment: Получилось)

autoit.opt("MouseCoordMode", 2)
autoit.mouse_click("left", x, y), 

при этом в Autoit v3 Win Info нужно выставить Coord ->Client , тем самым получить координаты мыши.